# Синтаксис механизма static

Tags: java, static

что значит строчка static SomeThing mThing;  ?
   static это ж как бы обращение к классу без использования объекта,
   а здесь это выглядит  как статический объект но так наверное не может быть ,что эта запись значит ?

```
class SomeThing implements Runnable
{
public void run()       
 {
    System.out.println("Привет из побочного потока!");
 }
}

public class Program            
 {
     static SomeThing mThing;   

public static void main(String[] args)
 {
    mThing = new SomeThing();               

    Thread myThready = new Thread(mThing);  
    myThready.start();              

    System.out.println("Главный поток завершён...");
 }
}
```

пример с этой статьи https://habrahabr.ru/post/164487/

Comment: вы и обращаетесь к полю класса. а куда там ссылка из поля класса указывает - третичный вопрос.

Answer (score 3):

Это статичный член класса, поле в данном случае, к нему можно обращаться по имени класса без использования объектов.

Comment: но в классе SomeThing  это поле mThing не объявлено да и класс SomeThing  не static а обычный?

Comment: @mtb, нестатичные классы могут иметь статичные члены. Если не замечаешь, то и метод main статичный. Поле объявлено static для примера скорее всего, чтобы облегчить доступ к нему из метода main, иначе пришлось бы создавать объект.

Comment: @mtb вы что-то путаете..... `mThing` является как раз таки типом `SomeThing`, а не то, что данное поле должно быть объявлено в том классе.......это же бред бредовый......... Объявлено данное поле с данным типом как раз таки в классе `Program`.....что говорит о том..... что в классе `Program` будет статическое поле `mThing`, типа `SomeThing`, к которому можно в любой момент обратится .....`Program::mThing` например из другого класса...... или просто как `mThing` из статического метода того же класса

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, для джавы просто Program.mThing

Comment: да действительно запутался - это ведь просто объявления  поля класса Program  с типом данных SomeThing

Comment: @DanielOlivo да...спутал с другим языком.... кстати `иначе пришлось бы создавать объект.` .....он итак там создается)

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, иначе пришлось бы создавать объект Program для доступа к нестатичному полю.

Comment: @mtb в джаве понятие статичный класс на самом деле говорит о принципиально отличном конструкте, не имеющем прямого отношения к статике. Все классы абсолютно одинаковы по отношению к статике, все могут иметь статичные переменные и методы.